# Join multiple values in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have an ajax call in codeigniter that will always return only two values: team_id1 and team_id2. I'm trying to join the two results as one value `value="1:2"` instead of `value="1", value="2"`. I tried `el.join(":");` but that doesn't do anything.  I'm assuming the `appendChild()` is prohibiting the join. Is there a work around? I need the values this way for a dependable dropdown. Thank you for looking!

```
function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
            var select = document.getElementById('match');
            if(emptySelect(select)){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.matchup.length; i++){
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = data.matchup[i].team_id;
                        el.value = data.matchup[i].team_id;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }   
        } else {
            alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }   
    }   
 }
```

Comment: first concatenate both value in one string with any special char like (:) as you mentioned than add in your option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
el.value = data.matchup[i].team_id1 + ":" + data.matchup[i].team_id2
```

or

```
el.value = data.matchup[0].team_id + ":" + data.matchup[1].team_id
```

The key is that you can use simple string concatenation to get your desired value

```
var team_1 = 'a';
var team_2 = 'b';

var value = team_1 + ':' + team_2; // = 'a:b'
```

Comment: @ekm383 :) I too did ask such questions at one time. I'd recommend this free online book http://eloquentjavascript.net if you are new to Javascript. And these videos, http://yuiblog.com/crockford/ once you are comfortable with it.